# How to allow specific ports to be accessible from specific IP addresses with iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, port, iptables

I have two servers: xxx.xxx.xx.xx and yyy.yyy.yy.yy. On the first one there's a postgres instance on its default port 5432 and I want it to be accessible only from this two particular IP addresses.

I tried following and it doesn't work for me:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s xxx.xxx.xx.xx --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s yyy.yyy.yy.yy --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 5432 -j DROP
```

After it `telnet xxx.xx.xx.xx 5432` can't connect from any of this two servers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm very new to iptables and don't have much understanding of what I'm doing wrong, sorry for dummy question

Comment: This isn't a programming related question, so it's off topic for Stack Overflow.  I would try on [su] or [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

How are your other chains? I mean, are you dropping your OUTPUT chain? I guess you have the OUTPUT dropping packets.

If you are dropping that OUTPUT chain, you need to set up the same for the it. After connecting on a tcp connection, there is always a reverse connection to the client (which matches the OUTPUT chain).

Other possible explanation of your problem could be the netmask for your ips... you should use `xxx.xxx.xx.xx/32` or `xxx.xxx.xx.xx/255.255.255.255` which is the same. And of course the same for your other ip `yyy.yyy.yy.yy`.

Good luck!